# How to write message longer than 8 bytes with char pointer in C TCP Socket server?

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, tcp, tcpserver

I have a char pointer array of many questions that are longer than 8 bytes.

```
        char* QuizQuestions[] = { "abcdefghijk", "..."};
```

I then have a char pointer that equals a random index of that char pointer array. This is to choose a random question to be sent to the client from the server.

```
        srand(time(NULL));
        char* q1 = QuizQ[rand() % ARR_SIZE(QuizQ)];
```

This section below includes 2 little test prints just to show what I'm trying to have done and understand why it's not working. Basically the output of the first print, prints the entire question. The size shows that q1 is only 8 bytes though. And then when it writes to go to the client. The client receives it as only 8 bytes.

```
        int sizeQ1 = sizeof(q1);
        printf("\nQ1: %s\n", q1); //Test
        printf("\nQ1 Size: %d\n", sizeQ1); //Test
        write(connfd, q1, sizeof(q1));
```

I understand it can only do 8 bytes cause a char pointer is 8 bytes, but **how would I go about sending the question longer than 8 bytes to the client?** Thanks!

Comment: Use `strlen(q1)` rather than `sizeof(q1)`. The former gives the number of characters in the string. The latter is only the size of a single pointer. Also, you may want to send the NUL character to delimit the msgs, in which case need `+1` on the length to send.

Comment: @kaylum you sir are a genius, thank you so much. That makes so much sense, works perfectly now! You saved me from hours more of confusion!!!